# MySQL group by concatenated columns or functions?

Tags: mysql

This appears to work,

```
 SELECT CONCATENATE(col1,col2) newcol,sum(othercol) 
        FROM mytable GROUP BY newcol.
```

Or even

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("%Y%m%d") as newcol,sum(othercol) 
        FROM mytable GROUP BY newcol.
```

Looking at these, one assumes the first example produces a count for each unique combination of col1,col2 as a string, the second example to produce a count for each day.

Having been bitten before by mysql e.g. silently ignoring "missing" columns in group by,

Does the above actually work, or are there any hidden gotchas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count rows, you should use count(*) instead of sum().

Otherwise, this pattern works fine.
  (I personally use "GROUP BY 1" to signify grouping by the first column).

Comment: Thanks - it's the sum I want, I just worte count in the text by mistake